# Calling method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

In my application I have an form to create new company. Here I have to enter company name and company url.Here is my code for the from.

```
<%= form_tag(controller: "/company", action: "add_startup_to_index", method: "post") do %>      
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter the name of the company..." required />
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Company URL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" placeholder="e.g. http://www.company.com..." required />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-conf" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-conf">Add Company</button>  
</div>
<% end %>
```

This is my method for saving above data.

```
def add_startup_to_index
@url = api_version_root + 'startups/new'
response = RestClient.post @url,
  { startup: {  friendly_name: params[:name],
                url: params[:url] 
            }
  }, api_token_hash

record = JSON.parse(response.body)
   flash[:info] = 'Startup has been added and Crunchbase sync started.'
   redirect_to('/startups/' + record['company_id']) && return
rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse => err
handle_rest_error http_code: err.http_code
end
```

This is working fine and I can save the companies. Now I want to validate the URL. For that I have below method.

```
def valid_url?(url)
  return false if url.include?("<script")
  url_regexp = /^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/ix
  url =~ url_regexp ? true : false
end
```

Since I am new for rails I have no idea how to call that method within my form. I had tried nested form_tag. But it is now allowed.

I tried as below.

```
<%= form_tag(controller: "/company", action: "add_startup_to_index", method: "post") do %>      
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter the name of the company..." required />
     </div>

    <%= form_tag(controller: "/company", action: "valid_url", method: "post") do %>      
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company URL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" placeholder="e.g. http://www.company.com..." required />
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-conf" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-conf">Add Company</button>  
</div>
<% end %>
```

Can any one help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

Lanka, if I understand you correctly, what you are looking for is **client side form validation**. Before HTML5 this was a tedious task involving JS. With HTML5, url validation is baked right in. Simply try to change the type of the input to url, i.e. change

```
<input type="text" id="url" name="url" ...>
```

to

```
<input type="url" id="url" name="url" ...>
```

Then, when a non-conforming url string is entered, the browser will not submit the form and automatically indicate the issue. This even works out of the box with a default url pattern. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url for more information on custom patterns, placeholders and much more.

Comment: Also worth noting is that OP's URL regex (which has no doubt been copied from some corner of the internet) is unreliable. For example, a `.london` domain name contains *six* characters in the TLD and therefore won't match the regex: `....\.[a-z]{2,5}`

Comment: @Tom Absolutely correct, and this is why I prefer baked-in industry standard solutions over DIY whenever possible. Keeping up with every standard change is simply impossible.

Comment: @AndreasGebhard But it allow to invalid URL also.

Comment: @Lanka What's your example of an invalid url? (And does your regex correctly pick that up?)

Comment: @Lanka No problem, if you have a url regex that suits your needs better, you can use it. Just assign it to the pattern keword of your input declaration: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url#pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url#pattern). This will override the built-in pattern. Anyways, this should solve the issue raised by your OP.